# iOS: Passing data between View Controllers

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, uiviewcontroller

I'm using Facebook API, and when the user select a place (CheckIn), I want to open another view and pass this place (FBGraphPlace), but in the "SecondViewController" the variable is null when the method "viewDidLoad" is executed.
When the user select the place:

```
if (secondViewController == nil)
{
    SecondViewcontroller *secondViewcontroller =
    [[SecondViewcontroller alloc]
     initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([SecondViewcontroller class])
     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self.secondViewcontroller = secondViewcontroller;
}

// How you reference your navigation controller will
// probably be a little different
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];

[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];

secondViewController.place = self.selectedPlace;

[self.navigationController
 pushViewController:self.secondViewcontroller
 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why do you have this:  baladaViewController.place = self.selectedPlace; when you're pushing secondViewController? Shouldn't it be secondViewController.place = self.selectedPlace?

Comment: Sorry, put wrong...Edited my post.

Comment: Are you sure that self.selectedPlace is not nil?

Comment: Yes! I put a NSLog of selectedPlace and printed it correctly.

Comment: Is the property place, typed strong? I can't think of why this shouldn't work. Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should do pushViewController first, then assign the place variable

Comment: "if (secondViewController == nil)", this variable and inside if command "secondViewController" variable are different, you redefined the variable twice

Comment: instead of using "secondViewController.place = self.selectedPlace;", try with "self.secondViewController.place = self.selectedPlace;"